# Format Y axis values, original figures in millions, only want to show first three digits

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting

Data for my Y axis (each country) has figures in millions:

```
{
  date: "1960",
  germany: "72542990",
  spain: "30327000",
  france: "46621166",
  italy: "50025500"
}
```

How do I write the `.tickFormat(d3.format(""));` on my Y axis variable to format the tick values so they show up in the Y axis scale like this:
0, 20 million, 40 million, 60 million, 80 million

Currently they show up as
0, 20000000, 40000000, 60000000,80000000

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Declare Formatter

```
formatValue = d3.format(".2s");
```

Use inside TickFormat

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return formatValue(d)});
```

to replace M with million try this..

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return formatValue(d).replace('M', 'million'); });
```

Comment: Thanks and do you know how to make it say "million" instead of M ?

Comment: thanks again! also how I take the number out two decimals?  like: 80.00 milllion  OR 80.00M?

Comment: do you know where is this `.2s` format documented? Thanks!

Comment: @ibiza  https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format
It explains well about `.2s` 
and 
https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_formatPrefix  for formatPrefix

Comment: Do you know if its possible to do this same replace method but with the python version of plotly?