# Plotly.py: Force axis units to thousands (k) instead of millions (M)

Tags: python, plot, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

Since the numbers on my x axis are somewhat large, they are showing in millions (i.e., **25.8512M**). However, I would like to force the format to show in thousands instead (i.e., **25,851.2k**).

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Scatter(x = [25.851e6, 25.852e6], y = [0, 1])])
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Following the suggestions in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907206/format-y-axis-values-original-figures-in-millions-only-want-to-show-first-thre) and this [d-3 format API reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#api-reference), I have tried setting the axis `tickformat` to `',.6s'`, for example, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no way to accomplish what you want in Plotly (look at this [similar question](https://community.plotly.com/t/need-help-formatting-axis/16725) asking to format billions 'B' as millions 'M')

The best solution I could come up with is to convert your data from millions to thousands, add the letter 'k', and use this list of strings as `tickvalues`. Not very elegant, but hopefully it accomplishes what you want.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

vals_in_millions = [25.851e6, 25.852e6]
fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Scatter(x = vals_in_millions, y = [0, 1])])

def convert_million_to_thousands(values):
    return [str(num/1000)+'k' for num in values]

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = vals_in_millions,
        ticktext = convert_million_to_thousands(vals_in_millions)
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this creative solution! Yes, I've seen that thread. Unfortunately, this would mean losing the resolution on zoom and other issues. In my case, I'm working with thousands of datapoints, so this conversion from numbers to factors is not really an option for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I had a feeling this solution wasn't generalizable, but I'll update my answer if I can think of anything. And if you figure anything out, please post your solution too as I would be curious if there's any workaround for this issue. Best of luck!